# Python - Tic Tac Toe - Computer Always Wins

Tags: python, tic-tac-toe

Currently using very simple code, have the game board defined as a multi-level array in a class named game

```
class game:
    board = [['#','#','#'],['#','#','#'],['#','#','#']]
```

win check is set up as below:

def check(board, player):

```
if (board[0][0] == player and board[0][1] == player and board[0][2] == player) or \
    (board[1][0] == player and board[1][1] == player and board[1][2] == player) or \
    (board[2][0] == player and board[2][1] == player and board[2][2] == player) or \
    (board[0][0] == player and board[1][0] == player and board[2][0] == player) or \
    (board[0][1] == player and board[1][1] == player and board[2][1] == player) or \
    (board[0][2] == player and board[1][2] == player and board[2][2] == player) or \
    (board[0][0] == player and board[1][1] == player and board[2][2] == player) or \
    (board[0][2] == player and board[1][1] == player and board[2][0] == player):
        
    win.player_won(player)
else:
    pass
```

The question I have is in regards to the 'Logic' of the game, I am currently writing out all of the possible combinations of plays using lots if if/elif statements. I'm sure there must be a more efficient way to complete this, but can't think what to use.

```
'''
        Below code is to prevent user from winning
This isn't the code in its entirety, just an example for the question 
        '''
        
        if board[0][0] == "O" and board[0][1] == "O":
            game.board[0][2] = "X" # Location 1 and 2 already have O's, block with X in Loc 3
            
        elif board [0][0] == "O" and board [1][0] == "O":
            game.board[2][0] = "X" # Loc 1 and 4 Already have O's, block with X in loc 7
            
        elif board [0][0] == "O" and board [1][1] == "O":
            game.board[2][2] = "X" # Loc 1 and 5 have O's, Block in Loc 9
            
        elif board [0][1] == "O" and board [1][1] == "O":
            game.board[2][1] = "X" # Loc 2 and Loc 4 have O's, block in Loc 8
            
        elif board [1][0] == "O" and board [1][1] == "O":
            game.board[1][2] = "X" # Loc 4 and Loc 5 have O's, block in Loc 6
            
        elif board [1][2] == "O" and board [1][1] == "O":
            game.board[1][0] = "X" # Loc 6 and Loc 5 have O's, Block in loc 4
            
        elif board [0][2] == "O" and board [0][1]== "O":
            game.board[2][0] = "X" # Loc 3 and Loc 5 have O's, block in loc 7
            
        elif board [2][0] == "O" and board [2][1] =="O":
            game.board[2][2] = "X" # Loc 7 and Loc 8 have O's, block in loc 9
            
        elif board [2][2] == "O" and board [2][1]== "O":
            game.board[2][0] = "X" # Loc 9 and loc 8 have O's, block in loc 7
            
        elif board [0][2] == "O" and board [1][2]== "O":
            game.board[2][2] = "X" # Loc 3 and loc 6 have O's, block in loc 9 
            
        elif board [0][2] == "O" and board [1][1] =="O":
            game.board[2][0] = "X" # Loc 3 and Loc 5 have O's, block in loc 7

        elif board [0][2] == "O" and board [0][1] == "O":
            game.board[0][0] = "X"
```

So what I'm basically asking is for anyones thoughts on what I can do for this that'd be more efficient than a bunch of if statements. Thanks

Comment: have a look into recursion and the MinMax algorithm

Comment: you want to have a for loop going through each square in the array calculating how many O's are directly next to it. You would then want the computer to place an X on the square with the most O's next to it. This doesn't cover every case and i'm sure the player would still be able to win but it should be a good start!

Answer (score 0):

Rudimentary approach, which can be heavily optimized, however, a good starting point for this use case:

`# CHECK WIN CONDITION` is a placeholder for that logic here. That is what would call `break` to stop the game.

```py
import itertools
import random

def printBoard(board):
    print ( "   |   |   ")
    print (" "+board[0]+" | "+board[1]+" | "+board[2]+"  ")
    print ("   |   |")
    print ("---|---|---")
    print ("   |   |")
    print (" "+board[3]+" | "+board[4]+" | "+board[5]+"  ")
    print ("   |   |")
    print ("---|---|---")
    print ("   |   |")
    print (" "+board[6]+" | "+board[7]+" | "+board[8]+"  ")
    print ("   |   |   ")

win_combos = [[0, 1, 2],
              [3, 4, 5],
              [6, 7, 8],
              [0, 3, 6],
              [1, 4, 7],
              [2, 5, 8],
              [0, 4, 8],
              [2, 4, 6]]

cpu_moves = []

player_moves = []

board = ['.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.']

def make_move(board, win_combos, moves):
  for two in itertools.combinations(moves, 2):
    for run in win_combos:
      if all(item in run for item in two):
        move = set(run).difference(set(two)).pop()
        if board[move] == '.':
          return move
  return None

while True:
  # ACCEPT PLAYER TURN
  p1 = int(input('Select a tile (0-8): '))
  board[p1] = 'p'
  player_moves.append(p1)
  
  # CHECK WIN CONDITION

  # MAKE CPU MOVE
  # check if cpu can win...
  move = make_move(board, win_combos, cpu_moves)

  # check if can block player win...
  if not move:
    move = make_move(board, win_combos, player_moves)
          
  # random placement
  if not move:
    move = random.choice([i[0] for i in enumerate(board) if i[1] == '.'])

  # MAKE MOVE
  board[move] = 'c'
  cpu_moves.append(move)

  # CHECK WIN CONDITION

  printBoard(board)
```

This approach defines all win conditions, and pulls out the combinations of two's for the cpu's moves and the player's moves, then compares these to the win combos defined to see if one more tile can be placed to win (`cpu_moves`) or block (`player_moves`), if not then choose a random slot.